# Selenium fails finding html element even though its visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I wanted to program a selenium script with python which can write an input in an testbox but selenium doesnt find the element. (and i know the scipt looks real bad right now but please only concentrate on the error)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

link = "https://kahoot.it/"
name = input("Name: ")
pin = str(input("PIN: "))
bots = int(input("Bots: "))

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for i in range(bots):
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://kahoot.it/%22,%22_blank");''')
wait1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div\[3\]/div\[2\]/main/div/form/input")))
inputid = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'game-Id')
inputid.send_keys(pin)
inputid.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
```

here is the console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\Users\\Blackbird\\Documents\\programmieren\\kahootjoinbot\\main.py", line 19, in \<module\>
wait1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div\[3\]/div\[2\]/main/div/form/input")))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\support\\wait.py", line 95, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I tried some other things like finding the element by Name or ID or css selector but it all didnt work.

Comment: when does the problem occur - when you have multiple bots? does the script work with a single bot? because when you `execute_script` you are opening a new window which the driver isn't really aware of so it may not be looking at the same window you think it should be looking at but te original window that you called the script in.

Comment: its also when only using one bot

Comment: @AndrewRyan is there an way i can make the driver look at the new tab?

Comment: I don't think you need to escaped square brackets - have you tried just `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/main/div/form/input` as the xpath? also, are you absolutely sure that that's the correct xpath? (Double-check by searching inspecting the window opened by selenium)

Comment: @Driftr95 i copied the xpath with chrome from inspector

Comment: @Jakob but did you inspect again in the selenium window just in case it's different there? [and did you try the unescaped version?] also, as JakyRuby said, it's not very reliable to use full xpaths like that - you should depend more on identifying attributes that won't change. can you include a set of sample inputs so we can try to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

name = input("Name: ")
pin = str(input("PIN: "))
bots = int(input("Bots: "))

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for i in range(bots):
    driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://kahoot.it/%22,%22_blank");''')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i+1])
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='gameId']")))
    input.send_keys(name)
    input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Why is your code not working?**
Because you are using line `driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://kahoot.it/%22,%22_blank");''')`.

That line is opening a new tab, then when you do your next line `wait1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div\[3\]/div\[2\]/main/div/form/input")))` your are using the first tab, but you navigate in the second tab.

So, you are opening a second tab and trying to locate your element in your fist tab, that's why no matters what element you try to find in your first tab, because your first tab does not contain anything.

How to solve it? Navigate in your first tab using `driver.get("https://kahoot.it/")`

Or you can change to your new tabs using: `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i+1])` where `[i+1]` is the index of tabs you have. So first tab is 0 second is 1 and so on.

**Advices:**

- Do not use full xpaths, in the moment something change in the page your xpath will probably not be valid anymore
- You can wait for the element and save in a variable, as I did, then just use it for sendkeys, click etc.

Comment: sadly doesnt work

Comment: @Jakob could you give an example name/pin so that we can test it on our end as well?

Comment: @AndrewRyan name is not important choose something, pin example: 8253692

Comment: @JakyRuby i get an timeoutexception error as you can see in my question

Comment: @Jakob Copy paste my exact code and it will work, your problem is that you are trying to navigate to url with line: `driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://kahoot.it/%22,%22_blank");''')` and that will not work. If you copy paste my whole code, it should work. You have to navigate using `driver.get("https://kahoot.it/")` not your line

Comment: @JakyRuby yes but the problem is, that in my project i want selenium to just open new tabs

Comment: @Jakob okay, code edited, now it showld work

Comment: @JakyRuby tysm it works

Comment: @Jakob nice! Can you mark my answe as accepted? Thank you!